# Will HTTPS API for a mobile app protect against Wireshark and similar?

Tags: api, security, https, wireshark

Suppose I have a mobile app which makes API calls to a server using HTTPS.

Would a malicious user be able to install Wireshark +  Android emulator to inspect the API calls  and by doing so get access to sensitive data like an API key?

I guess my question is whether Wireshark (or some other tool) can inspect the request before it gets encrypted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you control the client, then of course yes. Anything the client knows, its user may also know.

Without controlling the client, no, an external attacker cannot inspect or change https traffic unless they know the session keys. For that, they would typically use a fake certificate and make the client accept it (it won't do it by itself, and we are back at controlling the client).

Answer (score 1):

> Would a malicious user be able to install Wireshark + Android emulator to inspect the API calls and by doing so get access to sensitive data like an API key?
>
> I guess my question is whether Wireshark (or some other tool) can inspect the request before it gets encrypted.

Yes this possible if the user controls the device he wants to intercept the API calls.

In the blog post [Steal that API Key with a Man in the Middle Attack](https://blog.approov.io/steal-that-api-key-with-a-man-in-the-middle-attack) I show how a proxy tool([MitmProxy](https://mitmproxy.org/)) can be used to intercept and introspect the https calls:

> While we can use advanced techniques, like JNI/NDK, to hide the API key in the mobile app code, it will not impede someone from performing a MitM attack in order to steal the API key. In fact a MitM attack is easy to the point that it can even be achieved by non developers.

In order to protect https calls from being intercepted, introspected and modified the solution is to use [certificate pinning](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning):

> Pinning is the process of associating a host with their expected X509 certificate or public key. Once a certificate or public key is known or seen for a host, the certificate or public key is associated or 'pinned' to the host. If more than one certificate or public key is acceptable, then the program holds a pinset (taking from Jon Larimer and Kenny Root Google I/O talk). In this case, the advertised identity must match one of the elements in the pinset.

and you can learn how to implement it in the article [Securing HTTPS with Certificate Pinning on Android](https://blog.approov.io/securing-https-with-certificate-pinning-on-android):

> In this article you have learned that certificate pinning is the act of associating a domain name with their expected X.509 certificate, and that this is necessary to protect trust based assumptions in the certificate chain. Mistakenly issued or compromised certificates are a threat, and it is also necessary to protect the mobile app against their use in hostile environments like public wifis, or against DNS Hijacking attacks.
>
> You also learned that certificate pinning should be used anytime you deal with Personal Identifiable Information or any other sensitive data, otherwise the communication channel between the mobile app and the API server can be inspected, modified or redirected by an attacker.
>
> Finally you learned how to prevent MitM attacks with the implementation of certificate pinning in an Android app that makes use of a network security config file for modern Android devices, and later by using TrustKit package which supports certificate pinning for both modern and old devices.

While certificate pinning raises the bar, its still possible to intercept, introspect and modify https traffic, because it can be bypassed, as I demonstrate in the article [Bypassing Certificate Pinning](https://blog.approov.io/bypassing-certificate-pinning):

> In this article you will learn how to repackage a mobile app in order to make it trust custom ssl certificates. This will allow us to bypass certificate pinning.

## Conclusion

While certificate pinning can be bypassed I still strongly recommend its use, because it will protect the https communication channel betwwen your mobile app and API server in all other scenarios where is not the user trying to perform the [Man in the Middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack):

> In cryptography and computer security, a man-in-the-middle attack (MITM) is an attack where the attacker secretly relays and possibly alters the communications between two parties who believe they are directly communicating with each other. One example of a MITM attack is active eavesdropping, in which the attacker makes independent connections with the victims and relays messages between them to make them believe they are talking directly to each other over a private connection, when in fact the entire conversation is controlled by the attacker. The attacker must be able to intercept all relevant messages passing between the two victims and inject new ones. This is straightforward in many circumstances; for example, an attacker within reception range of an unencrypted wireless access point (Wi-Fi[1][2]) could insert themselves as a man-in-the-middle.[3]

## Going the extra mile?

[OWASP Mobile Security Project - Top 10 risks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Mobile_Security_Project#Top_Ten_Mobile_Risks)

> The OWASP Mobile Security Project is a centralized resource intended to give developers and security teams the resources they need to build and maintain secure mobile applications. Through the project, our goal is to classify mobile security risks and provide developmental controls to reduce their impact or likelihood of exploitation.

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS request is encrypted on your host (client) before sending over the network, so it is not available for Wireshark. Wireshark can get hostname of the HTTPS web serserver you connect but not the URL.